# How to icon them at the same level?

Tags: css, html, angular, ionic-framework

How to icon them at the same level?

[image: view page]

Code:

```
<button icon-button block (click)="nextpage();"> Palmares
    <ion-icon style="float:right" name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
</button>
<button icon-button block (click)="nextpage();" icon-right> Classement
    <ion-icon style="float:right" name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
</button>
<button icon-button block icon-right> Cours
    <ion-icon style="float:right" name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
</button>
<button icon-button block icon-right> Site Web
    <ion-icon style="float:right" name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: add your tried code here instead image

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

actually I don't have any knowledge about Ionic but i'll give it a try with basic inline-css for the buttons.

```
<button icon-button block (click)="nextpage();"> Palmares
    <ion-icon style="position:absolute;right:20px;" name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
</button>
<button icon-button block (click)="nextpage();" icon-right> Classement
    <ion-icon style="position:absolute;right:20px;" name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
</button>
<button icon-button block icon-right> Cours
    <ion-icon style="position:absolute;right:20px;" name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
</button>
<button icon-button block icon-right> Site Web
    <ion-icon style="position:absolute;right:20px;" name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

This might do the job, good luck!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please vote for my correct answer? Good luck!